# Each array to come up with a number, calculate out the location of the array

Tags: arrays

var a = [1,2,3]

var b = [1,2,3]

var c = [1,2,3,4]

Each array inside take out a number of a three digits.

A total of 36 kinds of combination of the above.

I want to compute the position of the each combination.

[1,1,1] position is 1

[1,1,2] position is 2

[2,2,4] position is？

I want to ask how much the position of a combination of them, is there a specific formula?

Comment: Are you using a specific language?

Comment: What do you mean by the "position of each combination?"

Comment: The formula depends on how you enumerate the permutations.

Answer (score 0):

Write three nested for loops. First one is for array a,second for b and third for c. That way you will first change the c for a new permutation than b, than a. Before going to for loop declare a variable called count which is 1. At the third loop increase that variable by one. Example:

```
int first,second,third,count=1;
       for(int i=0;i<a.size();i++)
    {
first=a[i];
for(int k=0;k<b.size();k++)
{
second=b[k];
for(int g=0;g<c.size();g++)
{
third=c[g];
count=count+1;     //count++
}
}
}
```

This is written in C++. But you get the idea.You can put if statements inbetween to find the number of the permutation that you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var a = [1,2,3];
var b = [1,2,3];
var c = [1,2,3,4];

var all = [a,b,c];
var allCount = [b.length * c.length, c.length, 0];

function getIndex(combo) {
    var count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < combo.length; i++) {
        var pos = all[i].indexOf(combo[i]);
        if (pos < 0) {
            throw new Error(combo[i] + "Not effective elements");
        }

        count += allCount[i] * pos;
    }
    count += combo[combo.length - 1];
    return count;
}

console.log("index of [2,2,4] is " + getIndex([2,2,4]));
console.log("index of [1,1,1] is " + getIndex([1,1,1]));
console.log("index of [3,3,4] is " + getIndex([3,3,4]));
console.log("index of [1,2,3] is " + getIndex([1,2,3]));
console.log("index of [3,2,1] is " + getIndex([3,2,1]));
```

The output:

```
index of [2,2,4] is 20
index of [1,1,1] is 1
index of [3,3,4] is 36
index of [1,2,3] is 7
index of [3,2,1] is 29
```